# Windows 10 fall creator login all users on startup

Tags: windows, windows-10

I have 2 user accounts in my pc; one mine and one is of some other person.

Windows after update has started logging in both the users at the startup. How to stop it?

Answer (score 0):

Hide User Accounts in Windows 10

at Run type regedit

Once in regedit go to

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\WindowsNT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon

In the left panel, right click on Winlogon and click New and click Key.

Type SpecialAccounts and press Enter

In the left panel, right click on SpecialAccounts and click New and click Key.

Type UserList and press Enter.

In right panel of UserList, right click on a empty area and click New then

click DWORD (32bit) Value.

Type in the name of the user account that you want to hide and press Enter.eg: 
Everyday Account.

In the right panel, right click on the user account name and click Modify.

To hide the user account – Type 0 and click OK. (number zero not the letter)

The link below includes detailed information about it.

https://www.windowscentral.com/how-hide-specific-user-accounts-sign-screen-windows-10

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere in the logon, the passwords are cached which might be auto signing.
Here is an advice if you do not have a password on the user accounts, try to setup one.
If you already have one. Then change the password.
Hope this works.